# Finding an orthonormal basis of $L^2[0,1]$ consisting of elements from $C[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Problem:

> Let $f \in L^1[0,1]$ but $f\notin L^2[0,1]$. Is there an orthonormal basis of $L^2[0,1]$ consisting elements {g_n} in $C[0,1]$ such that $\int g_n f = 0$?

To start with, one can show that $\{g \in L^2[0,1]| \int gf = 0\}$ is dense in $L^2[0,1]$. It follows that one is able to extract an orthonormal basis out of this subspace. It remains to show further that this basis can be chosen from the subspace of $C[0,1]$ if possible. I wonder whether this is correct and how to finish the last step.